# Restarting numbering within partition once value change

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, ranking, row-number

I'm struggling with quite simple (I think) topic, which I can not get to run.

An example data:

```
|ready_signal|timestamp          |
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:25|
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:24|
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:23|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:22|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:21|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:19|
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:18|
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:15|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:10|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:09|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:04|
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:03|
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is, to get maximal value of timestamp, within every ready_signal change.
So the result should look like:

```
|ready_signal|timestamp          |
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:25|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:22|
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:18|
|0           |2017-03-17 17:58:10|
|4           |2017-03-17 17:58:09|
```

I was trying with partitioning function, with `ROW_NUMBER` etc. but without success. I can not partition over none of this columns. Partitioning over ready_signal, will return only two values (and with use of ORDER BY within partition).

I think, somebody definitely have had the same issue. Is like, I would need a single unique partition number, but every time ready_signal value will change.

Sorry, for not posting the example code.
This is what I was experimenting with:

```
SELECT ready, 
    timestamp,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ready ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS readyTime
FROM bubu
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

I also tried to pick up some max values:

```
SELECT ready, 
    timestamp,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ready ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS readyTime
FROM bubu
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: show your attempted code as well, don't worry if it doesn't work, it shows effort on your part and you might not be that far off.

Comment: do you have another ordering column as you have repeating timestamp values with different ready signals? how do you know their order?

Comment: @Tanner untortunately not. This is realy a signal, which changes within the time, but it will be constantly logged, and I need to know the timestamps, when the signal changes its value, along with its value

Comment: Your sample data isn't distinguished enough - you have multiple rows with identical timestamps, such that it's not possible (from just this data) to determine an order.

Comment: Sorry ... copy paste problem :-) Acctually, timestamps are unique, you can assume that. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close but suffers from the issue I have commented on the question - because the timestamps aren't unique, it's possible to get different result sets. In this case, I *frequently* get another `0` row for `2017-03-17 17:58:09` since it's conceivable that one of them occurred before the `4`.

Anyhow, the way to write this is that you want to select the rows that either *have no successor* or where the successor has a different value for `ready_state`. Once you re-state the question like that, the code practically writes itself:

```
declare @t table (ready_signal int,timestamp datetime)
insert into @t(ready_signal,timestamp) values
(4,'2017-03-17T17:58:25'),
(4,'2017-03-17T17:58:24'),
(4,'2017-03-17T17:58:23'),
(0,'2017-03-17T17:58:22'),
(0,'2017-03-17T17:58:21'),
(0,'2017-03-17T17:58:19'),
(4,'2017-03-17T17:58:18'),
(4,'2017-03-17T17:58:15'),
(0,'2017-03-17T17:58:10'),
(0,'2017-03-17T17:58:09'),
(0,'2017-03-17T17:58:09'),
(4,'2017-03-17T17:58:09')

;With Numbered as (
    select ready_signal,timestamp,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as rn
    from @t
)
select
    t1.ready_signal,t1.timestamp
from
    Numbered t1
        left join
    Numbered t2
        on
            t1.rn = t2.rn - 1
where
    t2.rn is null or --No successor
    t2.ready_signal != t1.ready_signal --Successor different
```

Results:

```
ready_signal timestamp
------------ -----------------------
0            2017-03-17 17:58:09.000
4            2017-03-17 17:58:09.000
0            2017-03-17 17:58:10.000
4            2017-03-17 17:58:18.000
0            2017-03-17 17:58:22.000
4            2017-03-17 17:58:25.000
```

(You can add an explicit `ORDER BY` if the order of the result set is important to you)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, this will give you the exact required output as described in your question.

```
DECLARE @SAMPLEDATA TABLE(READYSIGNAL INT,TIMESTAMPP DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @SAMPLEDATA VALUES
(4,'2017-03-17 17:58:25'),
(4,'2017-03-17 17:58:24'),
(4,'2017-03-17 17:58:23'),
(0,'2017-03-17 17:58:22'),
(0,'2017-03-17 17:58:21'),
(0,'2017-03-17 17:58:19'),
(4,'2017-03-17 17:58:18'),
(4,'2017-03-17 17:58:15'),
(0,'2017-03-17 17:58:10'),
(0,'2017-03-17 17:58:09'),
(0,'2017-03-17 17:58:09'),
(4,'2017-03-17 17:58:09')
;WITH SAMPLEDATA
AS
(
SELECT *,1 COL FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 100))SNO,*
 FROM @SAMPLEDATA)T WHERE SNO=1
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.SNO,T2.READYSIGNAL,T2.TIMESTAMPP,
    CASE WHEN T1.READYSIGNAL=T2.READYSIGNAL THEN T1.COL ELSE T1.COL+1 END
        FROM SAMPLEDATA T1 JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT     100))SNO,*
 FROM @SAMPLEDATA) T2 ON T1.SNO=T2.SNO-1
)
SELECT READYSIGNAL,TIMESTAMPP FROM
    (SELECT READYSIGNAL,MAX(TIMESTAMPP)TIMESTAMPP,MAX(SNO)SNO FROM     SAMPLEDATA     GROUP BY COL,READYSIGNAL)RESULT ORDER BY SNO
```

**OUTPUT**

```
------------------------------------------
--READYSIGNAL   TIMESTAMPP
------------------------------------------
    4           2017-03-17 17:58:25.000
    0           2017-03-17 17:58:22.000
    4           2017-03-17 17:58:18.000
    0           2017-03-17 17:58:10.000
    4           2017-03-17 17:58:09.000
-----------------------------------------
```